# How to add given explode effect to image onclick in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code in which i have an `image` in `img tag`,

I have a `code for explode` the image ....

I `want to add this explode effect for onclick of image`.

How to add this explode effect to image onclick in jquery...

```js
$("img").explode();

$("img").explode({
  omitLastLine = false,
  radius = 80,
  minRadius = 20,
  release = true,
  fadeTime = 300,
  recycle = true,
  recycleDelay = 500,
  fill = true,
  explodeTime = 300,
  maxAngle = 360,
  gravity = 0,
  round = false,
  groundDistance = 400,
  ignoreCompelete = false,
  land=true,
  checkOutBound,
  finish,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="dist/jquery.imgexplode.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="jquery.imgexplode.js"></script>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
```

Comment: It seems you have a syntax error in your code snippet (when you run it). Can you fix that first please? Because sometimes syntax errors are related to the rest of the code not working.

Comment: @virginia i tried but cant fix it

Comment: I was about to say that your might be referencing the wrong url for the imgexplode library. However, Im starting to think that this error is not your mistake. You have a better chance of an answer when contacting the author of this package directly by opening an issue there (not SO)( https://github.com/blackmiaool/jquery-image-explode/issues). Because if you look at [his demo here](http://blackmiaool.com/jquery-image-explode/playground.html) right click at the page and choose 'inspect element', go to the tab 'console' and you will see the same error you are having in your code snippet.