# Image burst onclick not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

i have a code for `image  burst` when i `click` the `button`...

I have assigned a pic for it from picsum

it is now not bursting the image...

Where is the problem how to correct it?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/easyTree/easyTree.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/easyTree/easyTree.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img-explosion-demo" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" height="300" width="300"/>
    <button style="position:fixed;right:0;top:0;width:100px;height:50px;" onclick="explodeImage()">Explode image</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/imgexplode/jquery.imgexplode.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var $target = $("#img-explosion-demo");

        function explodeImage() {
            $target.explodeRestore();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $target.explode({
                    maxWidth: 15,
                    minWidth: 5,
                    radius: 231,
                    release: false,
                    recycle: false,
                    explodeTime: 320,
                    canvas: true,
                    round: false,
                    maxAngle: 360,
                    gravity: 10,
                    groundDistance: 150,
                });
            }, 300)
        }
        explodeImage();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at a line like this `<script src="js/imgexplode/jquery.imgexplode.min.js"></script>` so where do you expect this to be stored? in a `js` folder on the StackOverflow site`?

Comment: Please check my comment in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803477/how-to-add-given-explode-effect-to-image-onclick-in-jquery Besides the wrong relative url it is actually an error in the library self, so you should post an issue in the GitHub repository there (not SO).

Comment: I couldn't get the problem out of my mind and reproduced the error at my local pc, that's why I'm so sure :)

Comment: @virginia thanks for valueble time

Comment: You're welcome :)